# Move html & body up to top when img is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have images that when clicked, resize. However, I would like it so that no matter how far the user scrolls, when an image is pressed the html and body will move to the top. I added an animation to the resize script but it seems to not be recognized.

```
  $(".images img").on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected'); 
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.active').offset()   

            }); 
    });
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/qSDP5/

EDIT*

I put a sticky header to the top of the page and used

```
$('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#sticky').offset().top

        });
```

But it doesn't seem to want to scroll to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because not only you don't have any element with the class of active, but also you are not defining the coordinate direction of that element you want to access, because of that your script doesn't scroll to that.

change this line :

```
scrollTop: $('.active').offset()
```

to this if you want to scroll to the top of the page

```
scrollTop: 0
```

or you can scroll to an element which resides in your html something like:

```
scrollTop: $('#header').offset().top
```

see this: http://jsfiddle.net/qSDP5/1/

Comment: How can I make it so that it snaps the image to the top. Here's the example, when you click on an image. http://www.jamiewolfond.com/. Please see edit in first post!

Comment: what do you mean by snapping the image to the top. in that example, it transforms the image only..

Comment: Scroll down to a couple images then when you click one the whole page will snap to the top of the image. At least thats what it seems to me. Maybe its the image thats snapping to the top of the viewport?